# What is the center of error ellipse?

Tags: survey, error

Is the center of error ellipse representing true value or observed value?

Comment: Are you referring to the error ellipse plots like we see in OLS or ridge regression?

Comment: If an error ellipse had to be centered at the true value, of what use would it be in any statistical problem, where the objective is to estimate the *unknown* true value?